# Issue Installing Composer on Hosted Web Server

Tags: linux, laravel, webserver, composer-php

I’m having a heck of a time trying to install composer (to install Laravel) on my server. I’m accessing my web server via the built-in terminal in Coda 2. These are the commands I’ve been trying to run:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

The curl command executes fine, but when I try the move. I get the following error:

```
mv: inter-device move failed: `composer.phar' to `/usr/local/bin/composer'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system
```

I tried to run the move with `sudo` per the Composer website, but that results in these errors:

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

I’ve been trying to google search some to figure it out, but I haven’t had much success. I'm not too savvy with server issues like this, so that has made it hard for to figure out what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "hosted" server do you mean it's shared with other people? If so, you likely don't have sudo access nor should you be putting stuff in `/usr/local/bin`. You can install Composer into your home directory somewhere and put it in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I'm not sure. A local web host gave it to me for free after I had used his services for a few freelance customers.

Comment: Chances are very good you're on a shared host, then. Something like `mv composer.phar ~/bin/composer` and putting `export PATH="~/bin:$PATH" in your `.profile` will probably suffice.

Comment: ok, I was able to successfully move `composer.phar` to `~/bin/composer`, but I'm not able to call it without using the full command `php-cli ~/bin/composer/composer.phar about`. I ran `echo $PATH` and `/home6/mattalte/bin` is part of the output string. It doesn't seem like composer can be called globally.

Comment: You want composer to be at `~/bin/composer`, not `~/bin/composer/composer.phar`.

Comment: ok, hopefully last question. I moved it to `~/bin/composer` and when I run `composer about`, I get an error saying composer should be ran from the php CLI. At least it recognizes the `composer` command now. 

Any thoughts?

Comment: No clue. Ask your host.